# Scala / Lift Mapper - unsigned MappedInt

Tags: scala, lift, mapper

Is it possible to define an unsigned mapped Integer in Lift? I could not find anything about it.

```
class Project extends LongKeyedMapper[Project] with IdPK {
    def getSingleton = Project
    ...
    object budget extends MappedInt(this) // should be unsigned!
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are not unsigned ints in scala or java, all you can do is write a runtime check. Something like this should do it: (haven't tested it)

```
object budget extends MappedInt(this) {
  override def validations = {
    ((value:Int) =>
      if (value < 0)
        FieldError(fieldOwner, Text("Budget must not be negative"))::Nil
      else
        Nil)
    :: super.validations
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, unsigned does not only mean that the value may not be negative but also implicits a different range (the positive range is doubled). Moreover, the schemifier should set an "unsigned" attribute in the database (in my case mysql) so that it accepts large ints - ie. bigger than 2147483647. But I guess that's no possible with Lift's Mapper?

Comment: @goldmar why not use `Long` instead?

Comment: I don't think the schemifier supports this. If you have such specific needs for your database schema, you can always create or modify it yourself.

Comment: Okay, I see... well, I did not know that this was a too specific need ;)

Comment: @Nishant of couse that's a possibility but it leads to MySQL using up more memory than needed